# find the most effective treatment in a Latin square with R

Tags: r, statistics, experimental-design

I have a latin square with various treatments A, B, C, D. I want to know the most effective, ie the treatment that takes a larger value.

```
data<-c(13.7,10.8,15.3,19.1,12.1,19.2,15.4,13.6,11.9,14.6,17.1,18.7,14.2,16.3,11.4,16.9)
treat<-c("B","D","C","A","C","A","D","B","A","C","B","D","D","B","A","C")
row <- factor(rep(1:4, 4))
col <- factor(rep(1:4, each = 4))
mat<-data.frame(row,col,data)
mat
#    row col treat data
# 1    1   1     B 13.7
# 2    2   1     D 10.8
# 3    3   1     C 15.3
# 4    4   1     A 19.1
# 5    1   2     C 12.1
# 6    2   2     A 19.2
# 7    3   2     D 15.4
# 8    4   2     B 13.6
# 9    1   3     A 11.9
# 10   2   3     C 14.6
# 11   3   3     B 17.1
# 12   4   3     D 18.7
# 13   1   4     D 14.2
# 14   2   4     B 16.3
# 15   3   4     A 11.4
# 16   4   4     C 16.9
```

Comment: ? `summary(lm.fit<-lm(data ~ row+col, data = mat))` `par(mfrow=c(1,2))` `plot(data~row+col, mat)` `anova(lm.fit)`

Comment: @Vlo, I think you need `treat` in there too.